# How to display a graph using tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

How can I click on the GUI button to display the graph that I have coded?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)
redbutton = Button(frame, text='Training 1', fg='red')
redbutton.pack(side=LEFT)
greenbutton = Button(frame, text='Training 2', fg='brown')
greenbutton.pack(side=LEFT)
bluebutton = Button(frame, text='Testing 1', fg='blue')
bluebutton.pack(side=LEFT)
blackbutton = Button(bottomframe, text='Testing 2', fg='black')
blackbutton.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Based on the code above, there are 4 buttons display in the graphical user interface. I would like to press on the `Training 1` button to display my graph below.

```
""" Plot """
plt.plot(scores_train, 'b')
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(['train'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Make your graphing code a function and associate it with the correct button.

Comment: To associate clicking on the `Button` to the function, add a `command=` option when creating it. Here's some [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/button.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import pyplot from matplotlib and then define the function for plotting the graph.
Suppose we call the function 'graph', it would look like this:

```
def graph():
   plt.plot(scores_train, 'b')
   plt.title('Model Accuracy')
   plt.xlabel('Epoch')
   plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
   plt.legend(['train'], loc='upper left')
   plt.show()
```

Then you need to add the command for the redbutton, like this:

```
redbutton = Button(frame, text='Training 1', command=graph, fg='red')
```

Hope this works for you!